# Difference in styling between <p> tag and <button> tag?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
 <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <p style="color:red !important">
                blabla<br />
                blabla<br />
                <button style="color:red !important" class="accessibilityBtn" id="opener" >blabla</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

I've intentionally added the !important on both as I wanted to demonstrate the problem Im having and didnt want any css related file to affect the result.
anyways I dont understand why the red color is different , I can only assume that it is related to the difference in both tags? one is a paragraph and one is a button?? but how does that make any sense?

** note- I do not have any kind of bold attribute anywhere.

display:

[image: display]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is just default button text settings. If you want all the text to be the same you just need to set the CSS settings equal. The picture below is the output I got from putting your code into an editor. As you can see the only difference is the font which is because it is the default button font.

[image]

Comment: so basically what you're saying is that somewhere in my .css file I have an attribute that tackles buttons. and even tho I change the color, theres still some missmatch between both elements?, because if I change the button tag to '<a>' for example the color will be as above.. so it must be something with button's css I suppose. thanks

Comment: Buttons have a default styling depending on the platform that you are working with. However by calling button in css, or whatever class/id it is, you can alter it just like any other text with characteristics like font-size, color, etc.